# iOS - iPhone Menu

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5

I was wondering what the menu is called that is used in the photo app like (UIMenuControll) or something. The menu that is shown then you press the action button. When you have the choice to like email the image, send is as a message and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that thing you're talking about is a `UIActionsheet`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).